# Identifiable protocol in swiftUI... id property... var vs let

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the Landmarks tutorial for SwuiftUI by Apple, is there some reason why the id property of the Landmarks struct is a var and not a let?

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct Landmark: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int 

// ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for editing in the swiftui tag -- I don't have the 1500 rep required to use it. merp.

Comment: The whole point of having it is to id the object so it should be a let.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently not. You can safely turn the id into a let and all will work fine.

In fact, the `Identifiable` protocol has no conflict there. It only requires `id` to be gettable. It says nothing about settable:

```swift
public protocol Identifiable {

    /// A type representing the stable identity of the entity associated with `self`.
    associatedtype ID : Hashable

    /// The stable identity of the entity associated with `self`.
    var id: Self.ID { get }
}
```

Comment: this is not true at least for Picker element. If "id" is let for yout custom model, picker won't update the "selectedItem"